# How to filter records before series of queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have ~20GB of data in three tables. I'm generating reports which basically are 50-60 SQL queries which generate listings and statistics based on filtered data.

What is the best approach for filtering data before running those queries?

My first approach was to create temporary table for each data table in which I was copying filtered records, but copying megabytes or even gigabytes of data takes a lot of time. On the over hand applying filters in 60 queries (i.e. adding nested subquery like

```
WHERE id IN (some complex filter logic)
```

) also seems like waste of resources.

I would like to separate filtering and creating reports, service is intended to be public and generating report takes no more than 10s which is acceptable for now.

## Database and filtering details

There are three tables (private and foreign keys in brackets):

- accidents [id]
- vehicles [id, accident_id]
- participants [id, accident_id, vehicle_id (null if pedestrian)]

Example of the filters - accidents where pedestrian died:

- copy accidents where pedestrian died

```
INSERT accidents_temp 
    SELECT * FROM accidents WHERE id IN (
        SELECT accident_id FROM participants 
        WHERE injury="death" AND vehicle_id IS NULL
    )
```

- copy vehicles:

```
INSERT vehicles_temp 
    SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE accident_id IN (
       SELECT id FROM accidents_temp
    )
```

- copy participants:

```
INSERT participants_temp 
    SELECT * FROM participants WHERE accident_id IN (
       SELECT id FROM accidents_temp
    )
```

After that I'm running report queries which uses all three temporary tables, with JOINs, COUNTs, SUMs, and everything ;-)

Comment: Without seeing your schema (including indexes), there's no way to provide a useful answer. Also, 20GB of data isn't that much. Is it a few rows or millions? Are your filtered columns indexed? Are you using joins involving a couple of tables or dozens?

Comment: @SloanThrasher give me a moment, i'll update the question :)

Comment: +1 with @SloanThrasher, also these 50-60 queries, they might have poor performance, and needs to be optimized. So, you really need to take all possibilities into consideration.

Comment: iSR5 the worst of the queries takes around 2s on the whole dataset (~20 millions of records in each table) and I really don't know what to optimize there :/ I haven't implemented filtering yet.

Comment: With proper indexes on those three tables the right way IS to add the filtering on the 60 queries. You see, if you filter the data and then run your queries you are only adding a heavy step in the way. Again with proper indexes your 60 queries will run a lot faster than having to copy all that data. And adding those `where` would not be problematic if you are doing it in an application layer (I assume you are).